# Полный бэкап сайта средствами php

Tags: php

Всем добрый день! Подскажите как можно сделать бэкап сайта (т.е. все файл + БД всё в архиве) средствами php. И затем запускать php скрипт по cron. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет.

Самый простой способ, что приходит в голову - это `exec` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php))
Но, думаю, здесь очень все тесно связано с возможностями хостинга... 
Если есть ssh доступ, то тогда bash script который будет выполнять

```
mysqldump -uuser_name -ppassword db_name > file_name.sql

tar -zcf ./archive_name.tar.gz /public_html
```

mv и т.д.